# How is the authentication blob field of the table oauth_access_token table generated?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

i am using spring-security-oauth2 and all oauth related information are stored in a database. In the table oauth_access_token a field authentication is used.

I want to know what is stored in this field. Maybe someone can tell me were i can find the generation of this field in the spring-security-oauth2 source code.

I already figured out, that the field depends on the user object (or class), because whenever I change sth. in the user class, the content of the authentication field changes.
Is it possible to somehow deactivate the usage of this field for the authentication process or overwrite the method that generates the authentication field content?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what is stored in this field. Maybe someone can tell me were i can find the generation of this field in the spring-security-oauth2 source code.

take a look at `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore`

```
public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        String refreshToken = null;
        if (token.getRefreshToken() != null) {
            refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken().getValue();
        }

        if (readAccessToken(token.getValue())!=null) {
            removeAccessToken(token.getValue());
        }

        jdbcTemplate.update(insertAccessTokenSql, new Object[] { extractTokenKey(token.getValue()),
                new SqlLobValue(serializeAccessToken(token)), authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication),
                authentication.isClientOnly() ? null : authentication.getName(),
                authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(),
                // this one
                new SqlLobValue(serializeAuthentication(authentication)), extractTokenKey(refreshToken) }, new int[] {
                Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR });
    }
```

it uses `org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils` to serialize the authentication object.

> Is it possible to somehow deactivate the usage of this field for the authentication process or overwrite the method that generates the authentication field content?

Spring will create authentication object including the authorities for the user using this field.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to change that behaviour, so that only some parts of the user object are saved?

Comment: You can create your own `JdbcTokenStore` or extend it and override the method, just make sure you return the correct authetication object for spring to be checked.